# Autostart apache and mySQL Server on AWS

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, amazon-web-services, start

I've set up apache, mysql and php on my AWS EC2 instance, but how could it be done that these services are starting when the EC2 is starting? I've found the `chkconfig -a mysql` command but this just gives an error like `option -a not found`.

Comment: What is your distro?

Comment: @Khaled Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I read the [chkconfig man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig) for you and it says

```
chkconfig [--level <levels>] [--type <type>]<name> <on|off|reset|resetpriorities>
```

So

```
chkconfig --level 3 mysqld on
```

would start the mysql daemon at runlevel 3. Similarly

```
chkconfig --level 3 httpd on
```

would start Apache in runlevel 3.